# Magento store to work with SSL after server modification

Tags: ssl, https

I have a Magento store in a sub-directory. I don't mind having sub domain or a sub directory. I have a wilcard SSL certificate and I was able to make https work with my store.

But I needed to have an Apache modification for my Wordpress multisite installation installed in my domain root - from this:

```
<VirtualHost 109.73.236.14:443>
ServerName *.lumenco.ca
ServerAlias *.lumenco.ca
VirtualDocumentRoot /home/lumenco0/public_html/%1
ServerAdmin webmaster@lumenco.ca
UseCanonicalName Off
```

To this:

```
<VirtualHost 109.73.236.14:443>
ServerName lumenco.ca
ServerAlias *.lumenco.ca
VirtualDocumentRoot /home/lumenco0/public_html/%1
ServerAdmin webmaster@lumenco.ca
UseCanonicalName On
```

Because of that modification, my store sub domain (store.mysite.com) doesn't work so I had to change it to a subdirectory (mysite.com/store) but with a sub directory, https doesn't work correctly - it works for admin but I get an internal error when https is used on frontend pages.

I'm not really sure the best place ask this question but any ideas to fix this issue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Having sorta the same issue as GoDaddy changed servers. Did you try contacting your SSL provider and let them re-key it?

Comment: I think my issue is a bit more complicated, especially after talking to my host who say they don't think they can fix it unless that modification is removed (or alternatively use a wordpress plugin for a store). But I need that modification because of this conversation: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174861/ssl-wildcard-issue-for-wp-multisite-subdomains   and would like to still use magento, so just wondering if anyone has any ideas. Thanks anyway.